# How to Solve a Stars and Bars Discrete Math Problem

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

After a (not very successful) trick or treating round, Candice has 15 Tootsie rolls and 10 Twizzlers in her pillow case. Her mother asks her to share the loot with her three younger brothers.
(A) How many different ways can she do this? 
(B) How many different ways can she do this after her Mother warns her to give at least one of each type of candies to each of her brothers?

Comment: What have you tried?  Stars and bars is the right approach.  Just share each type of candy separately.

Comment: I've tried to solve it, but I missed the instruction on this and am having trouble reasoning it out on my own.

Comment: Missed the instruction for this problem or for stars and bars ?

Comment: For stars and bars

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at stars and bars first, with $15$ Tootsie rolls.
**One** way of distributing them to her $3$ brothers could be

$\Large\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.+\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.+\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.\boxed.= 15$

The Tootsie rolls (**n**) are "stars" and the $+'s$ are "bars", and it should be clear that we can get all the ways to distribute by just deciding where to put the $+'s$, which can be done in $\binom{17}2$ ways.

Note for reference that the number of $+'s$ (bars) will always be $1$ less than the number of children (**k**), thus the generalised formula $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

---

For part $1$, we distribute the two types separately (independently), and multiply, viz $\binom{17}{2}\binom{12}{2}$

For part $2$, we *pre-distribute* $3$ Tootsie rolls and $3$ Twizzlers, (one each) and distribute the balance using stars and bars, as before.

Comment: As commented by you in another answer, I have taken that Candice doesn't get any.

Comment: Note that the $\binom{17}{2}$ ways to distribute Tootsie rolls include $\newcommand{\bd}{\boxed.}{}+\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd+\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd= 15$ (first brother gets none), $\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd+{}+\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd= 15$ (second brother gets none), $\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd+\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd\bd+{}= 15$ (third brother gets none), and many other ways to give all the candy to just one or two brothers.

Answer (score 0):

1) If there were only 15 items on type 1 without restrictions, all you need to do ot distribute among 4 people is to see that it is in fact just $\binom{17}{3}$ because there are 3 bars
2) I this case just subtract 3 from each type and repeat the calculations in 1)

Comment: i think there are four people, not three.  She gets some, too.

Comment: Apologies, I should have read more carefully

Comment: Actually, my teacher said that Candice doesn't get any.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the approach still stands, just reduce the number of bars

Comment: @Alex For $(A)$, would the answer be $\left(\!\binom{3}{15}\!\right)\cdot \left(\!\binom{3}{10}\!\right)$?